# How do i make my jar file execute like a regular application from Terminal

Tags: command-line, java, execute-command

We all know that there are some commands i.e. executables we can run directly from terminal without having to set the full path for them. For e.g. all the executables in the `/usr/bin`

I have a jar file that I am currently running by the command `java -jar jarName.jar {arguments}`

Is there a way that I can run my jar as well similarly without writing the whole command `java -jar path_to_jar/jarName.jar {arguments}`

I would like to write something like

`appName {arguments}` and want the jar to get the arguments and execute just like it would have if I had written `java -jar path_to_jar/jarName.jar`

I am open to making the jar file an executable and putting it in /usr/bin so that it can accessed from anywhere. But I do not know how to do this. The following did not help at all [Tutorial to make jar executable](https://github.com/maynooth/CS210/wiki/Convert-Java-Executable-to-Linux-Executable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try to make a bash script that executes your command.
In your case it would look like this :

```
#!/bin/sh 
java -jar path_to_jar/jarName.jar "$*"
```

The "$*" takes all arguments given to the bash script and send them directly to your java program.
The last thing to do is to save your script in /usr/bin/myprogram.sh 
Then you will be able to execute it directly as a command in the terminal:

```
myprogram arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
```

Comment: `$@` is better than `$*`, since it doesn't change things if `IFS` is changed: ['That is, "$*" is equivalent to "$1c$2c…", where c is the first character of the value of the IFS variable.'](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html). On the other hand, ['"$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" …'](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html).

Answer (score 2):

First, `cd` into the directory containing your `.jar` file, and run:

```
chmod +x program.jar
```

Next, run:

```
nano ~/.bash_aliases
```

Then, add this line to the file:

```
alias custom_name='java -jar /full/path/to/.jar'
```

Exit nano saving changes, and restart the terminal window

Now, you can run it from anywhere like so:

```
custom_name {args}
```

Comment: isnt the alias set like that temporary for the session of the terminal?

Comment: @NickDiv - Yes, that's true. I've edited the answer to contain the permanent way.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up alias as well.

Open a blank file in your /home/user dir, like `nano ~/.bash_aliases`

And add  alias like:

`alias new_name='command'` in your case:

`alias mycustomcommand='java -jar path_to_jar/jarName.jar {arguments}'`

And `source` file, like `source ~/.bash_aliases`
Edit accordingly.

Comment: Is there any way I can make the jar an executable and put it in /usr/bin folder so that it executes like the rest of the executables from any location

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `.jar` file in `/usr/local/bin` (`/usr/bin` is for system executables, see [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)), `chmod a+x theFile.jar` and type `theFile.jar` to run it.

Since Linux (Unix, BSD* et al.) don't let user-controlled filenames influence execution, you could `mv /usr/local/bin/theFile.jar  /usr/local/bin/theFile`, and then run it via `theFile`.

Comment: Great, this looks like something I could work with. Let me try it out. Machine is currently under update. I will let you know as soon as I try it. Thanks.

Comment: I tried your solution and I was able to call the jar from random locations but it just started printing binaries.